# Predictive text in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

How can I get Excel to auto complete the word I am typing by using predictive text from a defined list?

Answer (score 2):

When you're running down a column entering values, Excel will remember previous values and suggest those that are the same as you have typed previously.

Alternatively, you could use Data|Data Tools|Data Validation to define a List of comma separated values. It won't autosuggest them any different to the above, but it allows you to restrict values in a group of cells to your pre-defined list and gives you the option of selecting from a drop-down list.

Comment: Thanks Rhys, but our application outputs into Excel and can't do validation lists. It can provide the lists, at the moment the user has to manually link the relevent cell to the required value in the list.